# Change form label font size

Tags: jqgrid

How do I change the font size of the form edit?
I tried changing:

```
.ui-jqgrid
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td
.form-view-label
```

but none makes a difference

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the font size only for the labels you can use

```css
.ui-jqdialog .CaptionTD { font-size: 16px; }
```

To increase the font size in the full form you can use

```css
.ui-jqdialog { font-size: 16px; }
```

**UPDATED**: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditFormFontSize.htm) where I used `.ui-jqdialog { font-size: 24px; }` to make differences to the font used in the grid more clear been seen. Select a row in the grid and click on Edit button of the navigator. You will see the form having fonts much larger as the font used in the grid.

Comment: Thanks it worked, .ui-jqdialog .CaptionTD did the labels which was the only item unchanged. .ui-jqdialog - did not see any changes

Comment: @JosePrendes: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditFormFontSize.htm) where I used `.ui-jqdialog { font-size: 24px; }` to make differences to the font used in the grid more clear been seen. Select a row in the grid and click on Edit button of the navigator. You will see the form having fonts much larger as the font used in the grid.